# How to get pdf rendition exactly same as displayed in outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook, aspose

I am trying to convert a '.eml' to 'mhtml' using **Aspose.Email** for Java.

**Issue:**

In **Microsoft outlook view** some **.emi** files may show both **Name** and **Email address** in the **To and From** section and some might have only **Name** in the **'To'** section.

***My try***

The OUTPUT, i am getting is based on the option i supply explicitly i.e. either MhtFormatOptions.WriteCompleteEmailAddress 
or MhtFormatOptions.WriteCompleteFromEmailAddress

**My query**
How to make it pick automatically  based on the **outlook view** without explicitly providing arguments for particular file as the target  rendition has to be exactly similar to what is ***displayed in the outlook***.

[image]

For example in the above screenshot only names in the **From** and **To** section are displayed in the Microsoft Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aspose Email 17.5](https://downloads.aspose.com/email/java/new-releases/aspose.email-for-java-17.5.0/) onwards, they have introduced **MhtFormatOptions.DisplayAsOutlook** in their api, which in turns displays header as in Outlook

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is no such way to pick it automatically based on the behavior of MS Outlook. However, in the upcoming version i.e. Aspose.Email for Java 17.2.0, this has been fixed. Stay tuned to our Product Release section for release of this new version. Feel free to write to us on [Aspose.Email forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx) if you have any further query about this.

I work with Aspose as developer Evangelist.